# Got an error while executing query {"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"syntax error at or near \")\""}

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, curl

I have a db with a primary key address

```
| Address               | other values...|
| ----------------------| -------------- |
| ed.nl                 | null           |
| spelletjes.nl         | null           |
| kinderspelletjes.nl   | null           |
```

I want to write a request that would delete rows that match the address that I pass in the array.

I have this in my **missing-urls.js** file

```js
async function deleteMissingUrls(request, reply) {
  try {
    const addresses = request.body;
    const { rows } = await pg.query(formatQry.deleteByAddress, [addresses]);
    reply.send({
      total: rows.length,
      items: rows,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    log.error(`Error while deleting. ${err.message}`);
    reply.internalServerError(err.message);
  }
}
```

and use this query in my **query/missing-urls.js** file

```
export const deleteByAddress = 'DELETE FROM metrics.missing_url WHERE address IN (?)';
```

When I run this request

```
curl -X DELETE -d '["ed.nl", "spelletjes.nl"]' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/api/missing/urls
```

I got an error.

```
{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"syntax error at or near \")\""}%
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're sending an array as data, then enclosing that array as an element in another array in the **query** call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use any operator `column = any(?)`

If you use node-postgres driver your code look like this:

```js
await pg.quert('DELETE FROM metrics.missing_url WHERE address = ANY($1)', [['address 1', 'address 2', ...]])
```

Comment: Thank you! This exactly what I was asking about. Works perfectly for me!

Comment: I have one question which is of course out of scope of previous question, but I hope you can answer to it. How can I handle situation with an error? I mean if you pass array as ["a", "b", "c"], but my table contains only row values ["a", "b", "z"]. For now it just delete ["a", "b"] and does not throw any errors that it could not delete "c".

Comment: You can use transaction andget count of delete item of count of deleted item equal with length of array you can commit else you can rollback transaction

Comment: Or you can select with condition before delete, if total length equal with length of array you can execute delete query, else you throw